# git tag associated with the git commit

Tags: git, azure-devops-rest-api, git-tag

I have the following PowerShell script to find out the latest commit in source/target branches:

```
$uriBranchStatus = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/diffs/commits?baseVersion=$branchSourcePath&targetVersion=$branchTargetPath&api-version=6.0"
$resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriBranchStatus -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host "Latest commit in $branchSourcePath is $($resultStatus.baseCommit)"
Write-Host "Latest commit in $branchTargetPath is $($resultStatus.targetCommit)"
```

Is it possible to find out the git tag associated with the latest commit in powershell script?

Comment: do you mean: using the devops API only ? or do you also have a clone of the project at hand where you can run plain `git` commands ?

Comment: using git: `git tag --points-at $latestcommit`

Comment: Using azure devops api